# How do I pass arguments to dlv debug

Tags: go, delve

How do I pass arguments to the debugged program when I invoke delve like this: `dlv debug`? I want to use `dlv debug` instead of `dlv exec` because `dlv exec` doesn't always find all sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can pass arguments to `dlv debug` the same way you do with `dlv exec`. Eg.:

`dlv debug -- -foo -bar`

Answer (score 1):

Per `dlv --help`:

```
Pass flags to the program you are debugging using `--`, for example:

`dlv exec ./hello -- server --config conf/config.toml`
```